# What does an X in the upper-left of a folder icon mean?

Tags: folders, error

I created this at the volume root per instructions to install MongoDB. I haven't seen this before. Is it invalid for me to create a top-level folder like this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X is actually a button.

It appears for example when you download a file or when you copy a folder/file.
It allows you to cancel the download/copy process.